# Showing Details in Django Admin for Many to Many Relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model where there are log class model and there is session class model. For each session there is several logs that can be recorded. So I created the following model:

```
class Log(models.Model):
    log_workout = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)
    log_exercise = models.CharField(max_length = 30, blank=True, null=True)
    log_order = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)],blank=True, null=True)

class ActiveSession(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    log = models.ManyToManyField(Log)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,blank=True, null=True)
```

In the admin I tried to use the inline so that I can see the details of each log in a session but it is only showing the full list and highlighting the added logs.

Here is the admin.py

```
class ActiveSessionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ActiveSession.log.through

class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Log
    inlines = [
        ActiveSessionInline,
    ]
```

My question:
Can I instead of showing the added log in the below image to show the logs that is selected as if I am viewing them from LogAdmin even if it is inline

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override the admin template and show the details.
You might even be able to add the javascript to do: if clicked remove from many-to-many field

But:

- You won't be able to edit the Logs without extra stuff- like a popup form + js + View to submit to
- `original.log.all` only contains things that are currently selected.. You'd almost have to either:

  - get into the form from `fieldset` and loop through the field's options to show all
  - or you could somehow pack extra data into the ModelAdmin

###### admin.py

```py
class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Log
    inlines = [
        ActiveSessionInline,
    ]

    # override template
    change_form_template = 'admin/logadmin_change.html'
```

###### logadmin_change.html

```html
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block field_sets %}

   
  <!-- Original Field Loop -->
  {% for fieldset in adminform %}
    {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
  {% endfor %}

  <!-- Custom Loop - 'original' is current Model being changed -->
  {% for i in original.log.all %}
    <div class="selectedLogs" pk="{{i.pk}}">
      {{i}} (make better looking tho)
    </div>
  {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```